# Running out of memory very quick with cudaMallocManaged

Tags: c, cuda

I have a C code and I want to translate that code to work with CUDA.

Explaining the complete problem would be very complicated and long, thats a part of it, where I have the problem.

Now the problem is: I need to create four AVL trees (the data to insert inside the trees are read from a file (the actual file, smaller one, have 255000 rows, but can be at maximum with 12 millions of rows). After inserting the four values on each corresponding tree, each node of the different trees will have a list of different nodes (one different per tree) but first I need to solve the problem that I have.

The problem is the following, if I create three of them there is no problem but if I create the four, CUDA gives an error "Out of memory".

Note, there are 410 code lines, the memory reservations with the function cudaMallocManaged(...) are on lines: 90 (function main) and 164, 176 and 190 (function auxCrearIndiceAVL). So I think that there is the error of it, but if so I could not see it.

Also I am working on a computer on Windows with Visual Studio with two NVIDIA 680 GTX (2 GB) and 32 GB of RAM. So with those 4 structures I think that there is enought memory for the structures. I dont know if need to activate any options on the CUDA setup or ...

Thanks for all in advance to anyone looking at this. Manuel Luis Aznar

The code is the following:

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

#define CHECK(r) {_check((r), __LINE__);}

/* Estructuras y tipos */

enum { IZQUIERDO, DERECHO };

typedef struct _nodo_especial {
    double m2i;
    double m1o;
    double m2o;
    struct _tipo_nodo *dato_next_index;
    struct _nodo_especial *siguiente;
    struct _nodo_especial *next_index;
} nodoEspecial;

typedef nodoEspecial* pNodoEspecial;


typedef struct _tipo_nodo {
    double dato;
    int FE;
    struct _nodo_especial *list;
    struct _tipo_nodo *derecho;
    struct _tipo_nodo *izquierdo;
    struct _tipo_nodo *padre;
} tipoNodo;

typedef tipoNodo* pNodo;
typedef tipoNodo* Arbol;

typedef struct REGcrowd {
    double m1i, m2i, m1o, m2o, x, y, color; // crowding
} EstrellaCrowding;

typedef EstrellaCrowding* pEstrellaCrowding;
typedef EstrellaCrowding* ListaEstrellasCrowding;

typedef struct _nodo_recubrimiento {
    double dato;
    pNodo enlace;
} nodoRecubrimiento;

typedef nodoRecubrimiento* pNodoRecubrimiento;
typedef nodoRecubrimiento* ListaRecubrimiento;


typedef struct _indices {
    Arbol indiceM1i, indiceColor, indiceX, indiceY;
    int numeroEstrellasIndice;
    int numeroNodosM1i, numeroNodosColor, numeroNodosX, numeroNodosY;
    ListaRecubrimiento listaRecubrimiento;
} tipoIndice;

typedef tipoIndice* Indice;
typedef tipoIndice* pIndice;

pNodo auxCrearIndiceAVL(Arbol *a, double dat, int *contador);


__global__ void kernel(Indice indice);
void _check(cudaError_t r, int line);
void check_memory_cuda(void);
__host__ __device__ void InOrden(Arbol a, int *contador);


/* Funciones de equilibrado */
void Equilibrar(Arbol *a, pNodo nodo, int rama, int nuevo);
void RSI(Arbol *raiz, pNodo nodo);
void RSD(Arbol *raiz, pNodo nodo);
void RDI(Arbol *raiz, pNodo nodo);
void RDD(Arbol *raiz, pNodo nodo);

int Vacio(Arbol r);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    check_memory_cuda();

    //Indice indice = (pIndice)malloc(sizeof(tipoIndice));
    Indice indice;
    CHECK(cudaMallocManaged(&indice, sizeof(Indice)));
    indice->indiceM1i = NULL;
    indice->indiceColor = NULL;
    indice->indiceX = NULL;
    indice->indiceY = NULL;
    indice->listaRecubrimiento = NULL;
    indice->numeroEstrellasIndice = 0;
    indice->numeroNodosM1i = 0;
    indice->numeroNodosColor = 0;
    indice->numeroNodosX = 0;
    indice->numeroNodosY = 0;

    FILE *fcrowd;
    int i;
    EstrellaCrowding estrellaCrowding;
    fcrowd = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    for (i = 0; !feof(fcrowd); i++) {

        fscanf(fcrowd, "%lf %lf %lf %lf %lf %lf", &estrellaCrowding.m1i, &estrellaCrowding.m2i, &estrellaCrowding.m1o, &estrellaCrowding.m2o, &estrellaCrowding.x, &estrellaCrowding.y);

        estrellaCrowding.color = estrellaCrowding.m1i - estrellaCrowding.m2i;

        pNodo auxM1i = auxCrearIndiceAVL(&indice->indiceM1i, estrellaCrowding.m1i, &indice->numeroNodosM1i);
        pNodo auxColor = auxCrearIndiceAVL(&indice->indiceColor, estrellaCrowding.color, &indice->numeroNodosColor);
        pNodo auxX = auxCrearIndiceAVL(&indice->indiceX, estrellaCrowding.x, &indice->numeroNodosX);
        //pNodo auxY = auxCrearIndiceAVL(&indice->indiceY, estrellaCrowding.y, &indice->numeroNodosY);
    }
    fclose(fcrowd);

    check_memory_cuda();

    printf("Imprimiendo el recorrido en InOrden del arbol M1i CPU\n");
    int contador = 0;
    InOrden(indice->indiceM1i, &contador);

    printf("El numero de nodos del arbol M1i es CPU: %d\n", indice->numeroNodosM1i);
    printf("Raiz arbol M1i CPU: %lf\n", indice->indiceM1i->dato);

    printf("El numero de nodos del arbol Color es CPU: %d\n", indice->numeroNodosColor);
    printf("Raiz arbol Color CPU: %lf\n", indice->indiceColor->dato);

    printf("El numero de nodos del arbol X es CPU: %d\n", indice->numeroNodosX);
    printf("Raiz arbol X CPU: %lf\n", indice->indiceX->dato);

    //printf("El numero de nodos del arbol Y es CPU: %d\n", indice->numeroNodosY);
    //printf("Raiz arbol Y CPU: %lf\n", indice->indiceY->dato);

    kernel<<<1, 1>>>(indice);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();


    return 0;
}

pNodo auxCrearIndiceAVL(Arbol *a, double dat, int *contador) {

    pNodo padre = NULL;
    pNodo actual = *a;

    /* Buscar el dato en el arbol, manteniendo un puntero al nodo padre */
    while (!Vacio(actual) && dat != actual->dato) {
        padre = actual;
        if (dat < actual->dato)
            actual = actual->izquierdo;
        else if (dat > actual->dato)
            actual = actual->derecho;
    }

    /* Si se ha encontrado el elemento, regresar sin insertar */
    if (!Vacio(actual))
        return actual;
    /* Si padre es NULL, entonces el arbol estaba vacio, el nuevo nodo sera el nodo raiz */
    else if (Vacio(padre)) {
        //(*a) = (Arbol)malloc(sizeof(tipoNodo));
        CHECK(cudaMallocManaged(&(*a), sizeof(tipoNodo), cudaMemAttachGlobal));
        (*a)->dato = dat;
        (*a)->izquierdo = (*a)->derecho = NULL;
        (*a)->padre = NULL;
        (*a)->FE = 0;
        (*a)->list = NULL;
        (*contador)++;
        return (*a);
    }
    /* Si el dato es menor que el que contiene el nodo padre, lo insertamos en la rama izquierda */
    else if (dat < padre->dato) {
        //actual = (Arbol)malloc(sizeof(tipoNodo));
        CHECK(cudaMallocManaged(&actual, sizeof(tipoNodo), cudaMemAttachGlobal));
        padre->izquierdo = actual;
        actual->dato = dat;
        actual->izquierdo = actual->derecho = NULL;
        actual->padre = padre;
        actual->FE = 0;
        actual->list = NULL;
        Equilibrar(a, padre, IZQUIERDO, TRUE);
        (*contador)++;
        return actual;
    }
    /* Si el dato es mayor que el que contiene el nodo padre, lo insertamos en la rama derecha */
    else {  /*if (dat > padre->dato) */
        //actual = (Arbol)malloc(sizeof(tipoNodo));
        CHECK(cudaMallocManaged(&actual, sizeof(tipoNodo), cudaMemAttachGlobal));
        padre->derecho = actual;
        actual->dato = dat;
        actual->izquierdo = actual->derecho = NULL;
        actual->padre = padre;
        actual->FE = 0;
        actual->list = NULL;
        Equilibrar(a, padre, DERECHO, TRUE);
        (*contador)++;
        return actual;
    }
}

__global__ void kernel(Indice indice) {

    printf("Imprimiendo el recorrido en InOrden del arbol M1i GPU\n");
    int contador = 0;
    InOrden(indice->indiceM1i, &contador);

    printf("El numero de nodos del arbol M1i es GPU: %d\n", indice->numeroNodosM1i);
    printf("Raiz arbol M1i GPU: %lf\n", indice->indiceM1i->dato);

    printf("El numero de nodos del arbol Color es GPU: %d\n", indice->numeroNodosColor);
    printf("Raiz arbol Color GPU: %lf\n", indice->indiceColor->dato);

    printf("El numero de nodos del arbol X es GPU: %d\n", indice->numeroNodosX);
    printf("Raiz arbol X GPU: %lf\n", indice->indiceX->dato);

    //printf("El numero de nodos del arbol Y es GPU: %d\n", indice->numeroNodosY);
    //printf("Raiz arbol Y GPU: %lf\n", indice->indiceY->dato);
}

void _check(cudaError_t r, int line) {
    if (r != cudaSuccess) {
        printf("CUDA error on line %d: %s\n", line, cudaGetErrorString(r), line);
        exit(0);
    }
}

void check_memory_cuda(void) {
    size_t free, total;
    cudaMemGetInfo(&free, &total);
    printf("CUDA Memory:\n\tFree ---> %llu\n\tTotal ----> %llu\n", free, total);
}

/* Recorrido de arbol en inorden, aplicamos la funcion func, que tiene
el prototipo:
void func(double*);
*/
__host__ __device__ void InOrden(Arbol a, int *contador)
{
    if (a->izquierdo) InOrden(a->izquierdo, contador);
    printf("%d ---> %lf\n", *contador, a->dato);
    (*contador)++;
    if (a->derecho) InOrden(a->derecho, contador);
}

/* Equilibrar árbol AVL partiendo del nodo nuevo */
void Equilibrar(Arbol *a, pNodo nodo, int rama, int nuevo)
{
    int salir = FALSE;

    /* Recorrer camino inverso actualizando valores de FE: */
    while (nodo && !salir) {
        if (nuevo)
        if (rama == IZQUIERDO) nodo->FE--; /* Depende de si añadimos ... */
        else                  nodo->FE++;
        else
        if (rama == IZQUIERDO) nodo->FE++; /* ... o borramos */
        else                  nodo->FE--;
        if (nodo->FE == 0) salir = TRUE; /* La altura de las rama que
                                         empieza en nodo no ha variado,
                                         salir de Equilibrar */
        else if (nodo->FE == -2) { /* Rotar a derechas y salir: */
            if (nodo->izquierdo->FE == 1) RDD(a, nodo); /* Rotación doble  */
            else RSD(a, nodo);                         /* Rotación simple */
            salir = TRUE;
        }
        else if (nodo->FE == 2) {  /* Rotar a izquierdas y salir: */
            if (nodo->derecho->FE == -1) RDI(a, nodo); /* Rotación doble  */
            else RSI(a, nodo);                        /* Rotación simple */
            salir = TRUE;
        }
        if (nodo->padre)
        if (nodo->padre->derecho == nodo) rama = DERECHO; else rama = IZQUIERDO;
        nodo = nodo->padre; /* Calcular FE, siguiente nodo del camino. */
    }
}

/* Rotación doble a derechas */
void RDD(Arbol *raiz, Arbol nodo)
{
    pNodo Padre = nodo->padre;
    pNodo P = nodo;
    pNodo Q = P->izquierdo;
    pNodo R = Q->derecho;
    pNodo B = R->izquierdo;
    pNodo C = R->derecho;

    if (Padre)
    if (Padre->derecho == nodo) Padre->derecho = R;
    else Padre->izquierdo = R;
    else *raiz = R;

    /* Reconstruir árbol: */
    Q->derecho = B;
    P->izquierdo = C;
    R->izquierdo = Q;
    R->derecho = P;

    /* Reasignar padres: */
    R->padre = Padre;
    P->padre = Q->padre = R;
    if (B) B->padre = Q;
    if (C) C->padre = P;

    /* Ajustar valores de FE: */
    switch (R->FE) {
    case -1: Q->FE = 0; P->FE = 1; break;
    case 0:  Q->FE = 0; P->FE = 0; break;
    case 1:  Q->FE = -1; P->FE = 0; break;
    }
    R->FE = 0;
}

/* Rotación doble a izquierdas */
void RDI(Arbol *a, pNodo nodo)
{
    pNodo Padre = nodo->padre;
    pNodo P = nodo;
    pNodo Q = P->derecho;
    pNodo R = Q->izquierdo;
    pNodo B = R->izquierdo;
    pNodo C = R->derecho;

    if (Padre)
    if (Padre->derecho == nodo) Padre->derecho = R;
    else Padre->izquierdo = R;
    else *a = R;

    /* Reconstruir árbol: */
    P->derecho = B;
    Q->izquierdo = C;
    R->izquierdo = P;
    R->derecho = Q;

    /* Reasignar padres: */
    R->padre = Padre;
    P->padre = Q->padre = R;
    if (B) B->padre = P;
    if (C) C->padre = Q;

    /* Ajustar valores de FE: */
    switch (R->FE) {
    case -1: P->FE = 0; Q->FE = 1; break;
    case 0:  P->FE = 0; Q->FE = 0; break;
    case 1:  P->FE = -1; Q->FE = 0; break;
    }
    R->FE = 0;
}

/* Rotación simple a derechas */
void RSD(Arbol *a, pNodo nodo)
{
    pNodo Padre = nodo->padre;
    pNodo P = nodo;
    pNodo Q = P->izquierdo;
    pNodo B = Q->derecho;

    if (Padre)
    if (Padre->derecho == P) Padre->derecho = Q;
    else Padre->izquierdo = Q;
    else *a = Q;

    /* Reconstruir árbol: */
    P->izquierdo = B;
    Q->derecho = P;

    /* Reasignar padres: */
    P->padre = Q;
    if (B) B->padre = P;
    Q->padre = Padre;

    /* Ajustar valores de FE: */
    P->FE = 0;
    Q->FE = 0;
}

/* Rotación simple a izquierdas */
void RSI(Arbol *a, pNodo nodo)
{
    pNodo Padre = nodo->padre;
    pNodo P = nodo;
    pNodo Q = P->derecho;
    pNodo B = Q->izquierdo;

    if (Padre)
    if (Padre->derecho == P) Padre->derecho = Q;
    else Padre->izquierdo = Q;
    else *a = Q;

    /* Reconstruir árbol: */
    P->derecho = B;
    Q->izquierdo = P;

    /* Reasignar padres: */
    P->padre = Q;
    if (B) B->padre = P;
    Q->padre = Padre;

    /* Ajustar valores de FE: */
    P->FE = 0;
    Q->FE = 0;
}

/* Comprobar si un árbol es vacío */
int Vacio(Arbol r)
{
    return r == NULL;
}
```

Comment: I have to add the following, i have compiled the posted code on Kubuntu Linux 14.10 using the same version of CUDA and it let me reserve space for a file with 254418 lines, in windows instead it let me do at maximum 1000...but the problem is that i want to reserve more amount of memory than that, because as i said each of each of the four trees has a single linked list of nodes...and if i put that it fails...so i think thre is anything to do with any configuration or setting...but i dont know what....so if anyone can help would be very useful for me

Comment: How much memory are you allocating? My best understanding of how CUDA allocates managed memory is that it always allocates  the device memory, and also allocates pageable memory in the same virtual address range on the CPU. If you are trying to allocate more managed memory than the GPU has device memory, NVIDIA's current design does not meet your requirements.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer

with the unified memory, because of the explanation pictures in the web i was supposing that you can reserve as much as the total memory of the host plus the memory of device (my PC have 32 GB RAM and the card have 2 GB, that makes a total of 34 GBytes) so i was not understanding why it was failing to allocate memory so quickly.

but yesterday night i was making some proof and i noticed that the maximum cuda memory that you can allocate is only the maximum memory of the device (in my case 2 GB).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday evening and night I was doing some cudaMallocManaged(...) testing, before that I was thinking that Unified Memory was using the Device Memory and when it runs out of space in the device they starts using the Host memory.

That was not like this, with the Unified Memory System of CUDA 6 cudaMallocManaged(...), we can only allocate as much memory as the device have.

thanks very much to ArchaeaSoftware for its answer

thanks to whole people reading and I wish all of you to enjoy CUDA as much as you can

see you soon guys.
Manuel

Comment: That's correct.  Currently (up to CUDA 7.0) any memory allocated with mallocManaged must be "shadowed" in physical memory on the GPU.  So you are limited by how much free device memory is available.

Comment: thanks for the coment Jonathan. do you think it would be any change on this, that will let us use part of the memory attached to the motherboard?¿?